# Button for <input> goes up when the font-size is too small

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a to-do list, but the button always goes a bit up whenever I make the text smaller. Any help?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input:first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
input {
  height: 19px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #222222;
  border: 0px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 299px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
button {
  height: 52px;
  width: 51px;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #0095FF;
  border: 0px;
  color: white;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #0077FF;
}
#output {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 350px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="input" placeholder="To-Do List"></input>
  <!--
-->
  <button id="+">+</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

And if possible, could you please tell me how I could automatically capitalize the first letter of the input without any external libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: Where's your JavaScript code? And what do you mean by "bottom always goes a bit up"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write button. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input:first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
input {
  height: 19px;
  background-color: #222222;
  border: 0px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 299px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 51px;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: #0095FF;
  border: 0px;
  color: white;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #0077FF;
}
#output {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 350px;
  height: 600px;
}
.form-1 {
    float: left;
}
.form {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div class="form-1">
  
  <input id="input" placeholder="To-Do List"></input></div>
  <!--
-->
  <div class="form">
  
  <button id="+">+</button></div>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change height of button

```
button {
    height: 50px;}
```

add float and remove margin-top of iput

```
input {
/* margin-top: 20px; */
float: left;}
```